# Hiding and showing div blocks in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner to html and in the below code , i have tried to hide and show contents using div blocks. I am able to hide/ show the second div block but on clicking the first div block it doesn't work! Dunno where it is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(which)
{
    if (!document.getElementById)
return
    if (which.style.display=="block")
which.style.display="none"
    else
which.style.display="block"
 }
 </script>


 <table>
 <tr><td><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv1'))"><label class="menuOff" style="font-size: 35px;">Div block 1</label></a></td></tr>

  <div id="adiv1" style="font:24px bold; display: none;">
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>Now you see me</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

  <tr><td><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))"><label            class="menuOff" style="font-size: 35px;">Div block 2</label></a></td></tr>


   <div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; display: none;">
   <table>
   <tbody>
   <tr><td>Now you see me</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>

   </table>

   </body>
   </html>
```

[image]

Comment: [jQuery slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: @mdesdev: this has absolutely nothing to do with why this code is not working and until the HTML is valid `slideToggle()` won't be working either!

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yeah, you're right ;)

Comment: @aarish: Check your code in the browser console, under the `element` tab you can see that your HTML has been altered compared to how you have it declared originally. the reason for this is that `div` tags cannot follow `tr` tags and the browser is trying to do it's best guess work to correct it. Hence it moves the invalid `div`s outside the tables. This might not be the same result between all browsers. Invalid HTML can be unpredictable at best.  [**validator.w3.org/check**](http://validator.w3.org/check) is a great tool to validate your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Your HTML is incorrect:

```
<table>
 <tr><td><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv1'))"><label class="menuOff" style="font-size: 35px;">Div block 1</label></a></td></tr>

 <!-- You can't have a div here -->
 <div id="adiv1" style="font:24px bold; display: none;">
```

Did you mean to have another table row in there?

```
 <tr>
 <td>
     <div id="adiv1" style="font:24px bold; display: none;">
 </td>
 </tr>
```

The same issue applies to the second div element

Comment: +1 Note for OP: The reason your second div works, although it is incorrectly placed following a `tr` tag as well is because the browser moves the complete `div` outside and below the first table.

Comment: @graham: ya actually i meant to have a div block inside the table row but learnt little later that that is semantically incorrect.. and this solves my problem thank you.. Btw jus clarify me , how do using div blocks inside <td> alone becomes right when <div> are not supposed to be used within <table>??

Comment: `<div>` can be used in a table, but it needs to be in the right place. The only direct child of a `<table>` element should be one of `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't your javascript but your HTML, it's not valid. Your javascript, although a bit odd (why do you check if getElementById exist? You used it to call the function!), is OK.

The problem is that your DIVs are floating in the middle of two TR. A table structure is:

```
<table>
  <tr> // a row
   <td></td> // one cell
  </tr> // end of a row
</table> end of table
```

What happens when you put stuff between Rows is undefined behavior. If you check your DOM in Chrome for instance, you'll see that your DIVs are actually empty and that the text (which you put in another table, my eyes..!) has 'escaped' out of them. And that's why it does nothing when you click: the style is updated, but there is nothing in it.

Funny thing: if you fix just the first DIV, the second DIV will start not working. It all depends on how the browser parse your invalid HTML and it's a bit random. Always close your tags, and always make sure you are following the basic structures... Like putting a TR within a UL instead of a LI (I have seen it.)

Comment: thanks for quoting down what happens to the div blocks when put within tables.. this explanation was expected by me

Answer (score 1):

the structure of your html is:

```
<table> <!-- to delete -->
    <div>
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
</table> <!-- to delete -->
```

It's not correct, when you remove the extra "table" tags it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors on the tags nesting.
Here example with less tags.
two buttons, each hides/shows different div.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- do not forget to declare type! -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Hide/show div</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function HideShow(which)
            {
                if (which.style.display=="block")
                    which.style.display="none"
                else
                    which.style.display="block"
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button onclick = 'HideShow(document.getElementById("div1"));'>Hide/Show div 1</button>
    <div id='div1' style='display:block'>This data is in div 1</div>
    <br>
    <button onclick = 'HideShow(document.getElementById("div2"));'>Hide/Show div 2</button>
    <div id='div2' style='display:block'>This data is in div 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to look into the `toggle` function provided with the JQuery Framework.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

The main problem seems to be that your HTML is incorrect, you were putting a div within the table element, which made it an direct child.

This will ofcourse throw an major error.

I've made a JSFiddle example for you http://jsfiddle.net/mNDN2/

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <label id="blockOne" class="menuOff" style="font-size: 35px;">Div block 1</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="adiv1">
    <td>asdfasdf</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#blockOne").on('click', function () {
    $("#adiv1").toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
#adiv1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why the code is not working and toggle will also not work as long as the HTML is invalid.

Comment: The HTML being incorrect is not `also` an issue but is the only issue and ones corrected the original code works - `toggle` won't fix invalid HTML. Also, there is no jQuery solution required nor requested by OP and is in this instance irrelevant.

Comment: still it's a cleaner solution, edited never the less.

Comment: Regardless, using jQuery is not answering the question nor was it the solution. You might as well post a solution based on any other JavaScript library which would be as random and fitting.

Comment: I quote "The main problem seems to be that your HTML is incorrect", in this context the JQuery one is a simple tip to look into for achieving his show/hide in an easier way.

Answer (score -2):

try to remove the a tag and on div block, add

```
onclick="hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))"
```

If it's not working, use jquery. To get an element with jquery

```
$("#adiv1") for example
```

and to hide, do

```
$("#adiv1").hide()
```

to show:

```
$("#adiv1").show()
```

Comment: jQuery will not make invalid HTML magically work. The `div` elements between the `tr` tags is still invalid.